# How to calculate the expectation value of position vector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, wavefunction

$$\psi (\vec{x})=Ae^{-(1/4a^2)|\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0|^2}e^{i\vec{p}_0\cdot \vec{x}/\hbar}$$

The wave function is like this, then how is the expectation value of position vector (not position) calculated?

Comment: What do you mean by "position vector (not position)?" In a multi-dimensional position space (e.g. R^3), position is a vector; there's no difference. Heck, even in R^1, position is a vector, it's just a 1-dimensional vector, so we don't usually use the little arrow.

Comment: I don't see the problem here, the integral of |psi(x)|^2 x_j d^3x is obviously equal to x0_j. Just do change of variables x_j = x0_j + u_j , the integral of |psi|^2 u_j d^3u is clearly equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean value of the position is given by $\langle \psi|\mathbf{X}|\psi\rangle$. Now insert the completeness relation for position states to get
$$\langle \psi|\mathbf{X}|\psi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \mathbf{x} |\psi(\mathbf{x})|^2\,\mathrm{d}V$$
From the OP, we see that the modulus squared of the wave function is
$$|\psi(\mathbf{x})|^2=A^2\exp\left(-\frac{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0|^2}{2a^2}\right)$$
Now we insert this into the above integral:
$$\langle \psi|\mathbf{X}|\psi\rangle=A^2\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \mathbf{x}\exp\left(-\frac{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0|^2}{2a^2}\right) \,\mathrm{d}V$$
Define $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0$,
$$\langle \psi|\mathbf{X}|\psi\rangle=A^2\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}(\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{x}_0)\exp\left(-\frac{|\mathbf{y}|^2}{2a^2}\right) \,\mathrm{d}V'$$
This splits into two terms. The first term is odd and vanishes when integrated. The second is proportional to $\mathbf{x}_0$. The constant factor will cancel the $A^2$ when properly normalized. (It is $(a\sqrt{2\pi})^3$.) Thus
$$\langle \psi|\mathbf{X}|\psi\rangle=\mathbf{x}_0$$